# XStream: using the value of class attribute as element name

Tags: xstream

The class attribute is an hot XStream topic: no one wants it.

The proper way of getting rid of it is to write a custom Converter (other proposed tweaks work only when marshalling, not when unmarshalling). A good working example is [here](http://old.nabble.com/%22class%22-attribute-and-the-references-to-subclasses-in-a-hierarchy-td19494734.html).

Unfortunately I need a Converter that works in a different way: I want to use the value of the class attribute as the name of the element that actually contains the attribute. For example, instead of

```
<codecData class="videoCodec">
...
</codecData>
```

and

```
<codecData class="audioCodec">
...
</codecData>
```

I want

```
<videoCodec>
...
</videoCodec>
```

and

```
<audioCodec>
...
</audioCodec>
```

What's the right way of doing this?  My attempt of writing such a Converter failed.

Assume that I have

```
public class MediumData {
    public CodecData codecData;
    public String otherInfo;
}

public abstract class CodecData {
    public String name;
}

public class VideoCodec extends CodecData {
    public String videoInfo;
}

public class AudioCodec extends CodecData {
    public String audioInfo;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you think using omitField() would work? like omitField(CodecData.class, "name"), then using an alias for codecData in MediumData?

Comment: Or xstream.aliasSystemAttribute(null, "class"), with an additional annotation on codecData

Comment: No, omitField() would completely remove codecData tag *and* its content; using aliasSystemAttribute to remove the class attribute and aliasing the codecData tag would not work either because I need two different aliases for codecData: "videoCodec" and "audioCodec".
I really think that a custom Converter is the only right solution but I have not found an example for my use case and documentation is not very detailed.